# How to "convert" htaccess rules into nginx rule?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

I would like to "convert" this rules into an nginx rule. I think the location block is the right place, but my solutions doesn't work.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried this

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1;
  rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?route=$1 break;
}
```

Comment: Expand on "doesn't work". What happens? What doesn't happen? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nginx `rewrite` directive is applied unconditionally, whereas you have many conditions in your rewrite rules. Use the [try_files directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) instead:

```
location = /index.php {
    # PHP options
}

location / {
    try_files /public$uri /public$uri/ /index.php?route=$uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your really very quick response. This works perfect :) `try_files /public$uri /index.php?route=$uri;`